# How to choose the second element of each cell-array in a larger cell-array?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

**Input**

```
hhh={{1,11},{2,22},{3,33},{4,44}}
```

**Intended output**

```
11 22 33 44
```

*P.s. `hhh{1}{2}`, `hhh{2}{2}`, `hhh{3}{2}` and `hhh{4}{2}` returns the right output but I am trying to find how to do it like `hhh{:}{2}`.*

Comment: Note that IF your array is guaranteed to be square and numeric (as some of the answers assume). You should seriously consider to use a matrix instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is guaranteed to be square and numeric, you should seriously consider using a matrix instead.

For example:

```
hhh=[1, 11; 2, 22 ;3, 33; 4, 44]
```

Now extracting the second column has become trivial:

```
hhh(:,2)
```

Using matrices is even worth considering if the data is not all of equal length (but within reasonable variation), simply because it stores more efficiently and handles so easily. Think about this example:

```
hhh=[1, 11, 111; 2, 22, 222 ;3, 33, NaN; 4, 44, 444]
```

Now it is still as easy as

```
hhh(:,2)
```

Answer (score 9):

One way would be to use `cellfun`

```
n=2
cellfun(@(x)(x{n}), hhh)
```

Which is essentially just a short hand for a for loop.

Or another possibly which is completely vectorized but will be more difficult to generalize is to first linearize and then select every second element:

```
temp = [hhh{:}]
[temp{2:2:end}]
```

Octave allows this in one line (Matlab does not unfortunately):

```
[hhh{:}](2:2:end)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the cells are guaranteed to have equal length you can use

```
cell2mat(vertcat(hhh{:}))*[0;1]
```

The multiplication chooses the second column of the matrix created by stacking the arrays in cells.

**EDIT:**

for general case you can use

```
n=2;
result = cell2mat(vertcat(hhh{:}))*sparse(n,1,1,size(hhh{1},2),1);
```

or

```
temp = cell2mat(vertcat(hhh{:}));
result = temp(:,2);
```

Comment: This works if cells are guaranteed to have length 2. Perhaps selecting the column is easier with an intermediate assignment: `M=cell2mat(vertcat(hhh{:})); M(:,2)`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I considered the OP smart enough to figure that out.